# Chrome Extension with webSocket

Tags: google-chrome-extension, websocket, pusher

I want to create extension that use Pusher service(http://pusher.com/) to send messages to the client, and I am getting the following error message:
Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. 
When I try the same code on simple html page it works.

```
Pusher.log = function(message) {
  if (window.console && window.console.log) window.console.log(message);
};

// Flash fallback logging - don't include this in production
WEB_SOCKET_DEBUG = true;

var pusher = new Pusher('key');
var channel = pusher.subscribe('channel');
channel.bind('event', function(data) {
  alert("test");
});
```

Do I need to change anything in order to make it run?

thx.